# jquery selector question

Tags: jquery, html

I ran into this code today:

```
$("#features").tabs("#someid > .someclass", {
    effect: 'fade',
    fadeInSpeed: 500,
    fadeOutSpeed: 500,
    rotate: true
});
```

I can't figure out what the `>` does in this code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means direct descendant (only one level down). In other words, `.someclass` elements have to be children of `#someid` but not grandchildren (or grand-grandchildren, etc.).

Relevant documentation: http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

Answer (score 2):

Essentially selects all elements with the 'someclass' class which are contained directly inside a element with ID 'someid' (but only direct descendants and not across multiple levels.)

See this: http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

Answer (score 0):

If an element in `someid` (meaning the id of the object) has the class of `someclass` (meaning the elements class) it'll only apply to that and only that, so if another element has `someclass` and doesn't have `someid` as its parent it won't apply.